# Finding distribution of $W=\frac{X}{Y-X}$

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, density-function

$X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, and 
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=6(y-x)$, $0 < x < y < 1$

If $W=\frac{X}{Y-X}$, how can I find $f_W(w)$ and show that $W$ and $Y$ are independent? I've calculated
$A=Y-X$
 $f_{X, A}(x,a)=6a$

$f_X(x)=3(x-1)^2$

$f_Y(y)=3y^2$

Now I can't find the support/domain of $W$ of $X$ to integrate to get $f_X$, $W(x,w)$
I've been stuck here for hours. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The $f_Y(y)$ is correct, just specify that $y \in (0;1)$

First of all observe that $w \in(0;\infty)$

the easiest way to proceed is to set the following system

$$\begin{cases}
w=\frac{x}{y-x} \\ 
z=y
\end{cases}
$$

That is like
$$\begin{cases}
x=\frac{w}{1+w}z \\ 
y=z
\end{cases}
$$

Calculate the Jacobian: $|J|=\frac{z}{(1+w)^2}$

and finally, via Fundamental Transformation Theorem you get

$f_{WZ}(w,z)=6z(1-\frac{w}{1+w})\frac{z}{(1+w)^2}$

Now you can easy factorize this density in the following way

$f_{WZ}(w,z)=3z^2\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(z)\times\frac{2}{(1+w)^2}[1-\frac{w}{1+w}]\mathbb{1}_{(0;\infty)}(w)$

That is also

$f_{WY}(w,y)=3y^2\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(y)\times\frac{2}{(1+w)^2}[1-\frac{w}{1+w}]\mathbb{1}_{(0;\infty)}(w)$

that's all. Now you have $f_Y(y)$, $f_W(w)$ and you have proved that

$f_{WY}(w,y)=f_W(w)f_Y(y)$